# How do I Import a library from github in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[I'm a newbie] I want to include a git library in android studio -> https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager 
I tried this. New-> import module -> downloaded file address
But it's giving some errors.

Comment: What errors does it give you?

Comment: the correct address is https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager.git . Please, not the .git at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have to import a module .
Just put the path in your build.gradle dependencies and use it as described.
e.g:

```
dependencies {

compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.0.3.2@aar'){
    transitive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

working code: add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to your project level gradle.